# Brackets calculations explained

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve how much is 
$$(x^3-2x-1):(x+1)$$
Please include steps and explanations. Is there and easy way to calculate those?
My logic is that I have to:
$$(x+1)(? ?)=(x^3-2x-1)$$
but is there another easier way?

Comment: just use division algorithm

Comment: you Need polynomial log division

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that $x=-1$ is indeed a solution to $x^3-2x-1$.

$$(x+1)(Ax^2+Bx+C)=x^3-2x-1$$

We can easily see that $A=1$ and $C=-1$

$$(x+1)(x^2+Bx-1)=x^3-2x-1$$

Now let $x=1$.

$$2(1+B-1)=1-2-1$$

$$B=-1$$

Edit:

In response to comment, compute quotient of $x^5-2x-1$ divided by $x+1$ using the same method. You might want to use long division or Horner's scheme.

check that $x=-1$ is a root. $$(x+1)(Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)= (x^5-2x-1).$$ Clearly, $A=1$, $E=-1$.
$$(x+1)(x^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx-1)= (x^5-2x-1).$$
Let $x=1$:

$$2(1+B+C+D-1)=-2$$

$$B+C+D=-1 \tag{1}$$

Let $x=2$:
$$3(16+8B+4C+2D-1)=32-4-1=27$$

$$15+8B+4C+2D=9 \tag{2}$$

Let $x=-2$:

$$(-1)(16-8B+4C-2D-1)=-32+4-1=-29$$

$$15-8B+4C-2D=29 \tag{3}$$

Adding equation $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$30+8C=38$$

$$C=1\tag{4}$$

Substitute $(4)$ back into $(1)$:

$$B+D=-2 \tag{5}$$

Substitute $(4)$ back into $(2)$:

$$8B+2D=-10$$

$$4B+D=-5 \tag{6}$$

Solving $(5)$ and $(6)$:

$$B=D=-1$$

Comment: I have no idea where $$2(1+B−1)=1−2−1$$ came from... Can you please explain?

Comment: I substitute $x=1$ into the previous equation $(1+1)(1^2+B(1)-1)=1^3-2(1)-1$

Comment: Can you please show me same logic on $$(x+1)(x^5-2x-1)$$ Thank you

Comment: Do you mean compute the quotient of $x^5-2x-1$ divided by $x+1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I stand correct. Can you show me please

Comment: Edited the answer. You might want to use Horner's scheme for the latest question perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

To divide by $x-a$, you can use *Horner's scheme*:
$$\begin{matrix}\text{coeff.}\\\text{of}&\\\\\\\\\times-1\quad\\\text{coeff.}\\\text{of}\end{matrix}\begin{array}{crrr}
x^3 &x^2&x&1\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\color{blue}1&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}{-2}&\color{blue}{-1}\\
\downarrow&-1&1&1\\
\hline
\color{red}1&\color{red}{-1}&\color{red}{-1}&0\\
\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow \\
x^2&x&1
\end{array}$$
Thus, the quotient is equal to $\;x^2-x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac { x^{ 3 }-2x-1 }{ x+1 } =\left( a{ x }^{ 2 }+bx+c \right) \\ x^{ 3 }-2x-1=\left( x+1 \right) \left( a{ x }^{ 2 }+bx+c \right) =a{ x }^{ 3 }+\left( b+a \right) { x }^{ 2 }+\left( b+c \right) x+c\\ a=1\\ b+a=0\Rightarrow b=-1\\ b+c=-2\Rightarrow c=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

let's do some transformations with $$x^{3}-2x-1=x^{3}-x-x-1=(x^{3}-x)-(x+1)=x(x^{2}-1)-(x+1)=x(x+1)(x-1)-(x+1)=(x+1)(x(x-1)-1)=(x+1)(x^{2}-x-1).$$
After division you get the answer: $x^{2}-x-1$